# Search on specific content

Tags: search

Hi is it possible to make a search box which are searching only for some specific content.

it should be a search box that should look at titel, ingrediensliste, body, and who have made it.

Comment: Can you be more specific - are these distinct content types or fields within a content type? For content types, an option like custom_search or search_config would work but this will be a little trickier if you only want to use certain fields. Also, are you using Apache Solr or just core Drupal search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [Custom Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search) module.

This module alters the default search box in many ways. If you need to have options available like in advanced search, but directly in the search box, this module is for you.

> ## Basic options
>
> The module adds options to select:
>
> - **which content type(s) to search**,
> - which specific module search to use (node, help, user or any module    that implements search),
> - which input type to use (with Elements),
> - advanced criteria
>
> For all these choices, there are options to switch between a select
> box, checkboxes or radio buttons, and also customize the selector
> label and the default - Any - text.
>
> ## Advanced options
>
> There are also options to:
>
> - change the default search box label,
> - add a default text in the search box,
> - add advanced search criteria,
> - change the default submit button text,
> - use an image instead of the submit button,
> - change the order of all the elements,
> - include some elements in a popup block,
> - add a filter to the results page,
> - show/hide basic and/or advanced search in the results page,
> - show/hide meta data in the results page,
> - multiple search paths

You can also achieve that by writing a custom module. Have a look at

[Build a Drupal 7 Content Type Search Block in 5 Easy Steps](http://envisioninteractive.com/drupal/build-a-drupal-7-content-type-search-block-in-5-easy-steps/)

Comment: @KennethGreen You're welcome. Glad :)